# CakePHP saving model using Session

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, session-variables

I am saving form data in a Session, and trying to save to a model called Property using the session array. Please see the array below. I think it has something to do with the Session array but I am not sure.

When I try to save like so, it does not save:

```
$this->Property->save($propertyData)  where $propertyData is the property array.
```

sql_dump:

```
INSERT INTO `fra`.`properties` (`type`, `address`, `city`, `state`, `zip`, `price`, `bed_rooms`, `bath_rooms`, `lot_size_sq_ft`) 
VALUES ('0', '2720 Acapulco way', 'modesto', 'ca', '95355', 310000, 4, 3, 6040)
```

The session array is:

```
Array
(
[house_details] => Array
    (
        [form] => Array
            (
                [section] => house_details
            )

        [Property] => Array
            (
                [type] => 0
                [address] => 2720 Acapulco way
                [city] => modesto
                [state] => ca
                [zip] => 95355
                [price] => 310000
                [prop_year_build] => 2007
                [prop_year_remodel] => 
                [bed_rooms] => 4
                [bath_rooms] => 3
                [garage_spaces] => 3
                [lot_size_sq_ft] => 6040
                [house_size_sq_ft] => 3720
                [stories] => 2
                [condition_rating] => 8
            )
```

Comment: Are you using `CakeSession::read('foo')` or what? Can we see more of the code?

Comment: As Nick said...can you show us the line before your save that sets the $propertyData array from the session please?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this quite simply.  You probably have a problem with `$propertyData` being set as the wrong thing so it doesn't provide a valid value for the model save.

What do you get if you do `debug($propertyData)`?

Does this work?

```
$propertyData = $this->Session->read('house_details.Property');
$this->Property->save(propertyData);
```